# MySQL/PHP login-error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

so I tried to make a login page for my localhost. I have a registration page that works fine, but I for some reason I can't make my login.php work

Can someone please help me?

```
<?php
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '123';
  $db = 'Data';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

 if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password"' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
      echo 'Du är inloggad!';
      exit();
    } else {
      echo 'Användarnamn eller lösenord stämmer ej med databas, var snäll försök igen';
      exit();
    }
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="login.php">
    Användarnamn: <input type="text" name="username" class="username" /><br/>
    <br/>
    Lösenord: <input type="password" name="password" class="password" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Logga in" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if I confuse you with some swedish echo's but that does not matter

Thanks

[image: Here is a Screenshot of my db]

Comment: I added a picture of my Database from phpmyadmin

Comment: Hint: `$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: By the way, is this for personal learning, or is this going to see the light of day on the WWW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have syntax error at line 13 check it and replace this line with this one

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: So I should delete the " and dots?

Comment: Also watch out for SQL injection even if mysql_query only takes 1 statement.

Comment: Actually the *real* error is a missing dot/concatenate in `password='".$password"'` where it should have read as `password='".$password."'`

Comment: @SwegreDesigns, remember to choose this as your answer if it worked for you. Also, always escape user input before passing it to DB and try to leave `mysql` that became deprecated, choose `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing dot from `password='$password'`.

You have another problem with this code. This is vunerable with SQL Injection.

Use this code:

```
"SELECT * FROM Project WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1"
```

And "mysql" API is deprecated now, use rather mysqli. It is faster too.